# Gravitation in solar system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, solar-system

What would happen to Earth’s motion if the Sun’ gravity was magically turned off? Assume that there are no other objects around.

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38289/34626

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing a rock on a rope in circles around you. You have to keep pulling on the rope to make the rock go in a circle. This is like the gravity of the Sun pulling on the Earth.

If you let go of the rope, the rock flies off in a straight line in the direction it was going when released. This is a line tangent to the circle. The Earth would do the same.

Answer (score 5):

It takes about 8 minutes for light from the sun to reach us. Gravity is a field whose disturbances travel at the same speed as light. 8 minutes after the sun is gone the Earth would be released from its orbit and keep going until it finds itself in some other orbit or not. [This is similar to how the bottom of a hanging Slinky does not instantly know that the top has been released. That information has to travel to the bottom of the slinky before it can fall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiyMuHuCFo4&ab_channel=Veritasium).

Answer (score 1):

In Newtonian mechanics where there is instantaneous transmission of force, the earth along with all other planets would no longer feel the centripetal pull of the sun and hence will travel in a straight line in the direction they were instantaneously moving then.

In Einsteinian mechanics, where gravity is not instantaneous, there would be a delay proportionate to the distance from the sun for each planet.  For the earth, this would be around 8 minutes, the time that light takes to travel from the sun to the earth.